# Array Syntax in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, formatting

I've been looking around, and I can't find a way to create an array like this:

```
var array:[Int] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0..
```

without typing a hundred zeros and commas. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks for your time.

Comment: you can use for loop to add zeros to nsmutablearray!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
var array = [Int](count: 100, repeatedValue: 0)
```